# What causes the discrepancy from HMAC functions in R vs Python when using .digest()?

Tags: python, r, amazon-web-services, hmac, ibm-cloud-storage

I am trying to write some functions to connect to IBM Cloud Object Storage using AWS Version 4 signing protocols.  There's some boilerplate code for doing this that works in Python over [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/hmac/hmac-signature.html#constructing-an-hmac-signature), but when I try to convert the code to R I find myself in a conundrum.

When using HMAC functions in R & Python the `.hexdigest()` method yields identical outputs for the same string in both languages:

```
# Python
import hmac
import hashlib
>>> hmac.new("key", "message".encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
'6e9ef29b75fffc5b7abae527d58fdadb2fe42e7219011976917343065f58ed4a

# R
library(digest)
> hmac("key", enc2utf8("message"), "sha256")
[1] "6e9ef29b75fffc5b7abae527d58fdadb2fe42e7219011976917343065f58ed4a"
```

If you use the `.digest()` method in Python from the `crypto` library - which the code from AWS/IBM suggests - then you get ASCII output.  I am able to approximate this ASCII output in R by changing the `hmac()` output to raw and then converting to character.  Below you can see it is not exactly the same - though it is close.

```
# Python
>>> hmac.new("key", "message".encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()
"n\x9e\xf2\x9bu\xff\xfc[z\xba\xe5'\xd5\x8f\xda\xdb/\xe4.r\x19\x01\x19v\x91sC\x06_X\xedJ"

# R
> rawToChar(hmac("key", "message", "sha256", raw = T))
[1] "n\x9e\xf2\x9bu\xff\xfc[z\xba\xe5'Տ\xda\xdb/\xe4.r\031\001\031v\x91sC\006_X\xedJ"
```

**What is causing the discrepancy here?**  The source code and docs for `.digest()` says that it returns a string of 8-bit data that may contain non-ASCII bytes.  **How can I replicate this output in R?**

Ultimately I believe this is what is causing my signatures to fail when trying to authenticate with IBM Cloud Object Storage.  Any help or alternative suggestions for HMAC libraries in Python/R would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Those basically are the same the only difference is how each language escapes non-ASCII characters. R is using octal representation and python is using hex. Those strings contain the same sequence of bytes.

Comment: I will look into this, thank you.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how I can proceed here?

Comment: It’s unclear to me exactly where your problem is occurring. Some sort of reproducible example would be helpful. Without it, there’s really no way to help.

Comment: I added the required libraries to the code snippet.   You should be able to reproduce the code above, and if you test the output for second code snippet you'll see that they aren't identical.  This causes issues when you try to build a signature.

Comment: The display on screen isn’t the same but the strings are the same. It seems like whatever error you are getting is probably downstream of the string creation. What exactly is the error or problem you are trying to solve (the string creation does not seem to be different between languages, it’s just that the languages have different ways of drawing them on screen). If you were to write each of those strings out to a file with the appropriate functions in each language, the files would likely be identical.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162562/discussion-between-raphael-k-and-mrflick).